# Why can't I nest a button inside another button

Tags: html

All sources say that you cannot nest interactive tags inside interactive tags in HTML, but there is no explanation as to WHY this is not possible. What will actually happen if I do this? Will some kind of error appear? Is it bad for accessibility (A11y)?

Comment: A button is an interactive element to trigger a script. A button inside a button as such makes no sense. It is like building a light switch in another light switch. If you press the nested button, do you want to press the inner or outer button? What will happen? It solely depends on the browser auto-correction feature and how that feature is trying to correct your invalid markup. Last but not least try to explain a blind person what an  interactive element is for and that there are further interactive elements within.

Comment: Let's say if you have 2 door bells on each other, when you press the door bell, which one will be rang? If you can answer this question, you already know the answer.

Comment: what if I have a card, that is like a link, it will navigate somethere, but inside of that card i want to have a button  that shows me some details?

Comment: `What will actually happen if I do this?` This should be pretty easy to test your self? (The nested button will be placed after "surrounding" button in the DOM). `but there is no explanation as to WHY this is not possible.` because the specification explicitly says it is not valid. `Will some kind of error appear?` if you validate your HTML and it has such nesting then yes you will get an error.

Comment: If you try to put them together, they will make confusing to users (not good in terms of UX). You should revisit your design if possible. @user0810

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, you are simply not allowed to nest buttons.

But you can create cards using divs. Here I delegate clicks from the container and test where the user clicks on the cards

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when the page loads
  const container = document.querySelector('main');
  container.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const card = event.target.closest('.card');
    const button = event.target.closest('.showmore');
    if (button) { // a button. Handle child elements too (if children change textContent below)
      const moreInfo = card.querySelector('.more-info');
      moreInfo.hidden = !moreInfo.hidden;
      button.textContent = moreInfo.hidden ? 'Show more' : 'Show less';
    } else if (card) {
      const url = card.dataset.url;
      //if (url) window.location.href = url; // does not work at SO due to frames
      if (url) console.log(url); // delete and uncomment above when happy
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="card" data-url="https://google.com">
    <h2>Card Title</h2>
    <p>This is some card content.</p>
    <button class="showmore">Show more</button>
    <div class="more-info" hidden>
      <p>Additional information goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-url="https://mdn.com">
    <h2>Card Title</h2>
    <p>This is some card content.</p>
    <button class="showmore">Show more</button>
    <div class="more-info" hidden>
      <p>Additional information goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```